Could zerophiliacs change sex after oral sex?
In the 2005 sci-fi movie Zerophilia, zerophiliacs are humans with an extra 'Z' chromosome that spontaneously change biological sexes after having sexual intercourse. They also can change through masturbation if sufficiently climaxing. There is also partial transformations in the movie but I don’t know how that works
Could they change via oral sex?

At first I thought this sounded dumb, but now that I've read the summaries/reviews, it seems like a genuine comedy worth watching. Not dumber than American Pie or something by the Farrelly brothers, anyway.

I would never have heard of this otherwise, so thank you for asking about it

@AndresF. - One of the reviews said that it was a good idea bogged down by poor execution. It was basically an interesting vessel to explore bisexuality and transgender identity, particularly for 2005, or it could have been, if it had managed to elevate itself beyond just explicit sexual comedy. Also, they apparently did not know that "zerophiliac" would mean "attracted to nothing." "Duophiliac" or "holophiliac," at least, please!

According to various plot summaries, Luke (in female form called Luca) is aroused enough just by flirting with Max to change back to (male) Luke.
